# Como concatenar variável no id do elemento? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Olá, estou tentando retornar informações de um arquivo .php em uma div especifica usando jQuery. A situação é a seguinte: A informação será retonarda para uma div com id="bkpLoja", porem esta div esta em uma secção com consulta no banco de dados e cada loja cadastrada possui a sua div no seguinte padrão "bkpLoja".$id_da_loja; Segue o exemplo

```
<div id=bkpLoja1>
conteudo...
</div>

<div id=bkpLoja2>
conteudo...
</div>

<div id=bkpLoja3>
conteudo...
</div>
```

o código jQuery esta assim

```
   function bkpLojas(id,bd) {
   var resposta = confirm("Deseja realmente realizar backup deste registro?");

   if (resposta == true) {
        $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url:'exemplo.com.br/up.php',
          data:'id='+id+"&bd="+bd,
          success:function(data){
            $("#bkpLoja").attr(id).html(data);
          },
          error:function(data){
            alert("Ops! Erro:05, entre em contato com o suporte!");
          }
        });
       }
     }
```

Já tentei assim tb:

```
$("#bkpLoja"+id).html(data);
```

Desde de já agradeço a ajuda atenção de todos!

Comment: O valor que está vindo em `id` está correto?

Comment: sim, o script funciona normal (tirando a parte q perguntei).  Ele só não retorna pra div correta o que o .php manda como echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das duas formas que usastes, somente a segunda forma:

```
$("#bkpLoja"+id).html(data);
```

... Preencherá a div correctamente.

O problema não é o seu código jQuery. O problema é o objecto `data`. Sugiro que o revise no consolo do navegador (na maioria dos navegadores, ele pode ser acessado ao se pressionar F12). Veja o valor do objecto `data`. Dependendo de como estiver formatado, pode ser que seu valor resulte em algo invisível em suas div's.

**Edição:**

Acredito que as div's deveriam ser declaradas na seguinte forma:

```
<div id="bkpLoja1">
    conteudo...
</div>

<div id="bkpLoja2">
    conteudo...
</div>

<div id="bkpLoja3">
    conteudo...
</div>
```

Note que as aspas fazem a diferença. Sem aspas o atributo `id` não é válido, então é possível também que o navegador renderize as div`s sem o atributo e por isso o jQuery não as localize.

Comment: antes eu estava fazendo $("#bkpLoja").html(data); e retornava o conteudo do .php corretamente, porém para a div bkpLojas. Sei abrir o console, mas não sei como faço para ver o valor de data.

Comment: No console, escreva apenas `data` e pressione Enter.

Comment: @JorgeBorgonhiBatista fiz uma edição importante. Acredito que pode ser outra causa de seu problema.

Comment: Valeu @Renan era isso mesmo, no arquivo .php onde as divs eram declaradas faltavam as aspas duplas, falta de atenção minha e obrigado!!!